# Extra text getting added after description when sharing on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sharer

So I have an application with a "Share on Facebook" link that is working great *EXCEPT* there is some text that gets added from the site's Terms & Conditions after the description and I can't for the life of me figure out where it's coming from! It doesn't appear anywhere on the page itself.

App details blurred out since it's not yet launched:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EW4Bc.jpg

Here's the code I'm using to generate the link:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXX
&link=http://THESITE.com/alpha/experiences/adventure/trekkin-us-virgin-way
&name=Trekkin%20the%20US%20Virgin%20Way
&source=http://THESITE.com/alpha/sites/default/files/exp/021613/USVI%20075.JPG
&caption=Two%20rules%20when%20visiting%20the%20U.S.%20Virgin%20Islands.%201)%C2%A0Respect%20and%20get%20to%20know%20the%20locals%20as%20they%20have%20resources%20that%20can%20make%20your%20trip%20a%20memorable%20one%20and%202)The%20first%20thing%20you%20do%20when%20you%20arrive%20to%20St.%20John%20is%20get%20a%20drink%20at%20Woody's%20for%20a%20%E2%80%9CPainkiller%E2%80%9D%20a%20local%20concoction!%C2%A0Pr
&redirect_uri=http://THESITE.com/alpha/experiences/adventure/trekkin-us-virgin-way
```

Any FB gurus out there have any ideas as to what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I should have been using "description" instead of "caption". It makes sense given Facebook's info on what to use these fields for: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/attachments/

Leaving this up for Google in case anyone has the same problem :)